# Can't get MVC Routing to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site and the url looks like this;

```
Home/LocationPage?locationId=f25a9ba4-54dc-4e6a-bdbf-094a5a6f7801
```

What I would like it to look like is;

```
Home/My Restaurant
```

I've tried mapping routes like this;

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Location",
            "{Controller}/{LocationName}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "LocationPage", LocationName = "" }
```

But can't seem to get the URL to change at all.

Comment: Routing doesn't change URLs; it adds URLs.  Do you want a redirect?

Comment: No i want the url to reflect a custom path

Comment: So what happens when you go to `Home/My Restaurant`? What precise problem are having?

Comment: the issue i am having is that i want to change the url from looking like the first url above and make it look like the second one above.

Comment: In other words, you want a redirect.  That's not what routing does; you need to make a redirect yourself. You also need to figure out how to retrieve the GUID.  (if names are unique, that's not a problem)

Comment: ok, so maybe it's url rewriting i'm after?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the route you just made, but you may need to add in a couple more things.

Add in a route constraint (or override the OnActionExecuting method on the controller or add a attribute to the action method) that looks up the the LocationName route parameter in the database and (if found) adds a locationId parameter to the route parameters.  Then create an action called LocationPage that takes a locationId (location Name is optional).

That way you get nice urls coming in, but the action doesn't need to do the lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a parameter called `LocationId` in your `Action` then you need to change your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Location",
            "{Controller}/{LocationId}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "LocationPage", LocationId = "" }
```

And don't forget that in this way you wouldn't get this parameter as `Guid` then you should make your logic to retrieve the `Guid` value by the provided name.